# display csv data in PyQt5

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pyqt5

the requirement of the code is to read multiple CSV files from a directory and converts each file into an individual Pandas DataFrame. The rows and columns of each dataframe is concat and to be displayed are specified by the input in the QLineEdit widget. The code uses the Pandas iloc method to select the specified rows and columns, and then displays the selected data in a QTableWidget. If the input is not a valid expression, an error message is displayed.

```
def loadFiles(self):
    options = QFileDialog.Options()
    options |= QFileDialog.ReadOnly
    fileNames, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(None, "QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()", "",
                                                "CSV Files (*.csv);;All Files (*)", options=options)
    if fileNames:
        rows_from_all_files = []
        for fileName in fileNames:
            with open(fileName, 'r') as file:
                reader = csv.reader(file)
                rows = []
                for row in reader:
                    rows.append(row)
                rows_from_all_files.append(rows)
        data_DF = pd.DataFrame(rows_from_all_files[0], columns=range(len(rows_from_all_files[0][0])))
        self.displayData(data_DF)

def displayData(self, data_DF):
    row_col_input = self.lineEdit_4.text()
    if row_col_input:
        try:
            # Use eval to evaluate the input string as a python expression
            selected_data = eval(f'{data_DF}.iloc{row_col_input}')
            if type(selected_data) == pd.DataFrame:
                # Convert dataframe to list of rows
                selected_rows = selected_data.values.tolist()
                # Set number of rows and columns in the table widget
                self.tableView.setRowCount(len(selected_rows))
                self.tableView.setColumnCount(len(selected_rows[0]))
                # Fill the table widget with the selected data
                for i, row in enumerate(selected_rows):
                    for j, data in enumerate(row):
                        self.tableView.setItem(i, j, QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
            else:
                # If the selected data is not a dataframe, it must be a series
                selected_row = selected_data.values.tolist()
                # Set number of rows and columns in the table widget
                self.tableView.setRowCount(1)
                self.tableView.setColumnCount(1)
                # Fill the table widget with the selected data
                self.tableView.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem(str(selected_row[0])))
        except:
            # If the input is not a valid expression, show an error message
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error", "Invalid input")
```

But I am not able to read any possible way pandas iloc method input for example  df.iloc[[0]] or df.iloc[[0, 1]] or df.iloc[:3] or df.iloc[[0, 2], [1, 3]] or df.iloc[1:3, 0:3]